# How to display a value and keep another value in my FormControl?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using [**text-mask**](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask) lib and it works pretty well.

Consider the following configuration of *mask*:

```
priceMask = Object.freeze({
  mask: createNumberMask({
    allowDecimal: true,
    decimalSymbol: ',',
    integerLimit: 7,
    prefix: '',
    thousandsSeparatorSymbol: '.'
  })
});
```

In my HTML, I have the following:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <input type="text"
         formControlName="maskedInput"
         [textMask]="priceMask">
</form>
```

As you may have noticed, in my mask configuration I'm limiting a field to have a value like this:

9.999.999,99

However, while I want to display this specific format to the user, I'm wanting to get a different value in my `control`, something like:

9999999,99

Is this possible?

I hope the question is clear enough. Thanks.

Here's a [**plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/tdKVza0DgDiZzjDXHJXa?p=info) that I created to illustrate the situation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd create a directive for this:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[numeric]' })
export class NumericDirective {
  constructor(private readonly model: NgControl) {}

  @HostListener('input') inputChange(): void {
    const newValue = this.model.value.replace(/\./g, '');
    this.model.control.setValue(newValue);
    this.model.valueAccessor.writeValue(newValue);
  }    
}
```

And in HTML, just include `numeric` attribute:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <input numeric
         formControlName="maskedInput"
         [textMask]="priceMask">
</form>
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/wuyTPCyFnvobBWYxKZcV?p=preview)